# Complete a form input with AJAX & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this HTML code to create the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/post.php" name="signup">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>URL:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="url" size="90" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" size="90"/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What I want to do is when a user enters a URL in the `url` input, I get the the title of the page, and the script outputs it to the `title` input. To get the title from an URL I have a PHP Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=url]').change(function() {
        // when the value of the url textbox changes
        // which happens when the textbox looses focus
        // send an AJAX request to the server script
        // to query the title of the remote url
        $.get('/gettitle.php', { url: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
            // when the AJAX request succeeds update the value
            // of the title input
            $('input[name=title]').val(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do I have to put this code inside `jQuery(document).ready($(function() {` ??

Comment: @Francesc, yes of course and you can see I've already done this in my example: `$(function() { ... });` is absolutely equivalent to `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... });`, it's just a shorthand.

Comment: well the script can go before the closing body tag therefore allowing you to get rid of any doc ready statements.